# python multithreading and print for Windows

Tags: python, windows, stdout, multiprocessing, pipe

I have been directed to turn code which has been using threading.Thread to now use multiprocessing.Process

my main problem is I am using Windows and these subfunctions expect to be able to print on to the Python Shell (IDLE)

does anyone have experience of how to do it?

my thoughts at the moment:

subclass the multiprocessing.Process so i can pass a Pipe or a Queue to the child process whcih will be used in a function which overrides **_*builtin*_**.print or sys.stdout.write

I would also need something in the parent process to simultaneously query multiple Queues or Pipes, gather the data into something i can print until all the child processes are completed

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the output interleaved as it happens, or is it okay for the output to come in a single lump? If the latter, then you can write something which captures stdout/stderr and sends the result back as in:

```
class CapturedException(Exception):
  def __init__(self, stdout_text, stderr_text, exc):
    self.stdout_text = stdout_text
    self.stderr_text = stderr_text
    self.exc = exc

def capture_call(*args, **kwargs):
  old_stdout = sys.stdout
  old_stderr = sys.stderr
  sys.stdout = stringio_out = cStringIO.String()
  sys.stderr = stringio_err = cStringIO.String()
  try:
      try:
          result = real_function_to_call(*args, **kwargs)
      finally:
          sys.stdout = old_stdout
          sys.stderr = old_stderr
  except Exception, err:
      raise CapturedException(stringio_out.getvalue(), stringio_err.getvalue(), err)

  return (stringio_out.getvalue(), stringio_err.getvalue(), result)
```

If you need interleaved output, displayed as it happens, then I'm not the right person to talk with. I've been looking towards ZeroMQ for a solution in this space, but don't know of a ZeroMQ which implements the multiprocessing API.

Comment: I would prefer as it happens, as I am dealing with long processes with a lot of output